# Tag manager & GA4 custom parameter doesnt show up in reports

Tags: google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions, google-analytics-4

I am facing an odd situation where a custom parameter I am sending with the GA4 purchase event doesnt show up in my reports.
I have configured the parameter as a custom dimension and double cheked it every way I can think of about 10 times.

When I test a purchase using tag manager preview & GA4 debug the value shows up as expected and for those purchases ends up all the way in my reports. However this is the only time.
I recently added the parameter under the "fields to set" on the GA4 configuration tag and got my hopes up high as it seemed to be the only thing I had missed, but after 2 days (its 3-4 days now) it was clear I dint help.

Like I mentioned I see the value in the datalayer, I see it in my tag and even with the purchase event when using the debug, but once the testing is over its not showing up in my reports.

I hope someone has an idea what could be causing this as I am eager to work it but running short on places to look at.
Thanks in advance
S.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several errors.
In Custom definition chek:

1. Check if the correct one is selected "scope" (for event parameter it must be "event")
2. The name in the "event parameter" field must match one to one with the one specified in the tag manager.
3. You will be able to see the values in the reports only after 24 hours, not earlier.

Comment: Thanks Mykola. I have verified the above, they are set up ok. I see the values when I test using tag manager preview, in GA4 debug view, and  in my reports, but only when on tag manager preview, after that no more. (this is repeatable). Its driving me mad. The background is : the website datalayer does 2 purchases pushes, one for universal analytics and one for GA4, both arent formatted exactly to  google standard. The variable I want is in the first push, I store it in a session variable. I only fire GA4 purchase tag on the second event, and (try) to include my variable in it.

Comment: Everything is correct. If you see it in debug mode, then everything is working. But this is not enough to see this data in reports. For the report, you need to set up a custom definition and then it can be used in reports. Alas, the debug mode misleads many.

Comment: Thabks Mykola. I did set up the custom definition also previously, with paying extra attention to scope and naming etc..  but still no data in the reports, I will see if expporting to bigquery would include the data.. but yeah totally dumbfunded why its not visible